# trouble inputting number array in postgres using loopback

Tags: postgresql, strongloop, loopback4

I have a table in postgres with a column called user_ids with its type set to integer[]

However, in defining the model for the table, I cannot seem to get it right, that when I try posting to the table, it always gives me an error. I have tried this:

```
 @property({
    type: "object",
    itemType: "number",
    postgresql: {
      dataType: "integer ARRAY"
    },
    name: 'user_ids'
  })
  userIds?: number[];
```

in which postgres throws the error: "message": "Unexpected number in JSON at position 109"
when I post this as the body of the call:

```
"userIds": {
    1
  }
```

If I try this:

```
 @property({
    type: "object",
    itemType: "number",
    postgresql: {
      dataType: "integer ARRAY"
    },
    name: 'user_ids'
  })
  userIds?: number[];
```

then the database throws the error: malformed array literal: "[1]"
when I put this in the body

```
"userIds": [
    1
  ]
```

Can someone tell me how to correctly define the model. I know postgres requires arrays to be in curly braces but no matter what I try, either loopback or postgres throws an error

Comment: I keep facing this issue as well. Have you found a solution?

Comment: Yea. I did this:
@property({
    type: 'array',
    itemType: 'number',
    postgresql: {
      dataType: 'integer ARRAY',
    },
})
userIds: number[]

Comment: @VikramKhemlani wouldn't this be specific to PostgreSQL and when DB is changed, this will no longer work.

Answer (score 2):

For me `@property({ type: 'array', itemType: 'number', postgresql: { dataType: 'integer ARRAY', }, })` did not work (tested 14 and 9.6 postresql), but it work for correct migration.

As mentioned in documentation for [loopback-connector-postgresql](https://github.com/loopbackio/loopback-connector-postgresql#loopback-to-postgresql-types) there are only String[] supported array type. In source code of connector (lib/postgresql.js) there is method toColumnValue, and check for arrays `const isArrayDataType = prop.postgresql && prop.postgresql.dataType === 'varchar[]';`

So easiest way is fork and add your check smth like this

`const isArrayDataType = prop.postgresql && (prop.postgresql.dataType === 'varchar[]' || prop.postgresql.dataType.includes('ARRAY'));`